# For loop is stuck at 0

Tags: java, android

I need to store multiple user data input , from one activity and passing the data over to another activity using intent . So i thought of using an array to store this values and add the total array to display the total

I tried to increment the int i but when i toastmessage the value of i , its stuck at 0

```
        int size = 1000;
        int i;
        String myArray[] = new String[size];
        for(i=0;i<size;i= i + 1){
            int sum = 0;
            Intent mIntent = getIntent();
            int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("CALORIE", 0);
            sum = sum + intValue;
            if(sum !=0) {

                myArray[i] = String.valueOf(sum);
                ToastMessage(String.valueOf(i));
                getIntent().removeExtra("CALORIE");

            }

        }
```

Im trying to have it to increment so i can store different value in different array

Comment: First thing I would try is to rewrite your for loop to be the following as it is more easily readable: for (i = 0; i < size; i++). Then I would check if maybe your if statement is only being satisfied when i is zero.

Comment: alright i did it , my if statement is only satisfied if there is a intent value thats passed over. I reset to default value of intent which is 0 after the if func.

Comment: When you say stuck at 0, do you mean to say it only iterates once, or that it iterates multiple times but `i` never advances?

Comment: i never advances

Comment: Well that makes sense because your sum value is only not equal to zero when the value that is being added to it (intValue) is more than zero, and that is only the case if an intent object is created. You need to use that information to decide why that would not occur when i is greater than 0.

Comment: Perhaps look at your getIntent() method (which I also suggest you document here) for clues.

Comment: Based on your code, the condition of sum!=0 is only satisfied when i==0, which means the intValue==0 when i>0. Check that line of code if you get anything wrong or not

Comment: thanks for your inputs , im still thinking of a way to let it wait till it recevies a value from intent and if it does recevie a value from intent , get the value , put in array , then clear it to default 0 and wait again

Comment: Just a hint here, while loops will work wonders in a wait() function.

Comment: reading up on it now , thanks zach

Comment: take Intent mIntent = getIntent(); method outside of the loop

Comment: tried the method but still at 0...

Comment: its either at 0 or loop 1000times oh my

Answer (score 0):

Your loop does not make sense.
With this line:

```
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("CALORIE", 0);
```

you get the extra with key `"CALORIE"`.
-If this extra does not exist then `intValue` gets the default value of `0` and `sum` remains equal to `0`, so the `if`'s condition is `false` and the loop continues with the next iteration in which you check again for the same extra of the same intent that does not exist!!!
So all the iterations up to 1000 do **nothing**.
-If this extra exists and its value is not `0` then the `if`'s condition is `true` and inside the `if` block you **remove that extra from the intent**.
So all the next iterations will check for that extra that does not exist any more and will do nothing.
I believe that you have to rethink the logic of your code as it is not clear what you try to achieve.
In any case this is not the way to do it.

Comment: the thing im trying to achieve here is to get the sum of all intent values coming from the other activity ,

Comment: `getIntExtra("CALORIE", 0);` is only **1** extra value.

Comment: example would be , user keys 10 , at the mainpage , it would display textview , and if user keys in 20 , main page will display 30 (20+10) etc.. I have achieved the outcome i wanted on the same activity but it somehow doesnt work the same if i pass it over as intent

Comment: In my answer I explained why your code does not work as you mentioned that it should work. The comments is not the way to present a problem. Post a question where you explain clearly what you want to do **including the code** you have in **both** activities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(String)` ?

```
  int [] myArray = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("CALORIE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

> I need to store multiple user data input , from one activity and passing the data over to another activity using intent . So i thought of using an array to store this values and add the total array to display the total

Then you're trying to solve the problem by reading the sent Intent multiple times with:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i= i + 1){
    ...

    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("CALORIE", 0);
    sum = sum + intValue;

    ...

}
```

which is incorrect.

It's because you only have an `int` value with `getIntExtra()`. And then you're trying to read it multiple times but it will always gives you the same value. So, it's unavailing.

For multiple data input, what you're really needs probably are [`getIntArrayExtra(String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntArrayExtra(java.lang.String)) or [getStringArrayExtra(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayExtra(java.lang.String)) methods.

You need to set the array with something like this:

```
int calories[] = {1,2,3};
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivityClass.class);
i.putExtra("CALORIES", calories);
```

then handle the value with:

```
Intent i = getIntent();

// get the array of calories
int calories[] = i.getIntArrayExtra("CALORIES");

for(i=0; i< calories.length; i++) {
    // do the sum here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try when i get home! will update u